# How do I use Telnet in Window 7?

Tags: windows, telnet

I enable Telnet Client and Server in Windows 7 32 bits but I don't know how to use Gmail from Telnet and What should i need to install in my computer?  I want to study How to use Gmail from Telnet from start.

Comment: you should not use gmail from telnet. period. telnet is not safe to use outside your LAN. this article shows how to connect to an smtp server from telnet, but just to test that its accessible: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718%28v=exchg.65%29.aspx

Comment: Nowadays you only use telnet to check whether you can access a TCP port for example, or in case it's mail service, just to test SMTP server can send or similar stuff. Avoid at all costs

Comment: heck using telnet inside you lan can be unsafe as well :)   using what part of gmail?  Since AFAIK Gmail *requires* SSL on their connections.  You would probably need to use something like openssl s_client

Answer (score 2):

Telnet in Windows 7 can be easily done by installing telnet client which is not installed by default. To install.

1. Go to Control panel.
2. Click on `Programs and Features`.
3. At left side, click on `Turn Windows features on or off`.

[image]

Go down in Windows Features box, and tick `Telnet Client` as shown above. Then press `OK`, and let installation complete.

That’s it, telnet client installation is done in windows 7.  When telnet client is installed, windows firewall settings also changed automatically to allow telnet packets.
Now if you type the same `telnet` command, you can get telnet console in windows 7.

<sub>[`Reference`](http://www.sysprobs.com/telnet-windows-7)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 7, Windows Server 2008 R2, Windows Server 2008 or Windows Vista you can use the following command line to install `telnet`:

```
dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient
```

or (deprecated):

```
pkgmgr /iu:"TelnetClient"
```

<sup>See: [Install Telnet Client](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx).</sup>

Then to use it, the syntax is: *telnet host port*, e.g.

```
telnet google.com 80
```

and you can type what you need to send. When finish, hit <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>]</kbd> then type `quit`.